# Regex to match dollar amount with uppercase letter or word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match some sort of amount, here are all possibilities:

```
$5.6 million
$4,1 million
$8,1M
$6.3M
$333,333
$2 million
$5 million
```

I have already this regex:

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion|[MB]illion)|[M])?
```

See [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mf4y1y/1).

But I'm not able to match those ones:

```
$5.6 million
$4,1 million
$8,1M
$6.3M
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `(?i)\$\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion)|m)?` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/Mf4y1y/2 (version with a word boundary at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)\$\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion)|m)?
```

If you need to make sure you do not match `m` that is part of another word:

```
(?i)\$\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion)|m)?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mf4y1y/2). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive option
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of `.` or `,` and then one or more digits
- `(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion)|m)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion)` - one or more whitespaces and then `thousand`, `million` or `billion`
  - `|` - or
  - `m` - an `m` char
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: This matches `'$3.3,3.3,3.3'`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your regular expression:

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\s+(?:thousand|[mb]illion|[MB]illion)|[M])?
```

`\$\d{1,3}` is fine. What follows? One way to answer that is to consider the following three possibilities.

**The string to be matched ends `' million'`**

This string (which begins with a space, in case you missed that) is preceded by an empty string or a single digit preceded by a comma or period:

```
(?:[,.]\d)? million
```

Evidently, "million" can be "thousand" or "billion", and the first in last might be capitalized, so we change the expression to

```
(?:[,.]\d)? (?:[MmBb]illion|thousand)
```

One potential problem is that this matches `'$5.6 millionaire'`. We can avoid that problem by tacking on a word boundary preventing the match to be followed by a word character:

```
(?:[,.]\d)? (?:[MmBb]illion|thousand)\b
```

**The string ends `'M'`**

In this case the `'M'` must be preceded by a single digit preceded by a comma or period:

```
[,.]\dM\b
```

You could accept `'B'` as well by changing `M` to `[MB]`.

**The string ends with three digits preceded by a comma**

Here we need

```
,\d{3}\b
```

Here the word boundary avoids matching, for example, `$333,3333'`. It will not match, however, `'$333,333,333'` or `'$333,333,333,333'`. If we want to match those we could change the expression to

```
(?:,\d{3})+\b
```

or to match `'$333'` as well, change it to

```
(?:,\d{3})*\b
```

**Construct the alternation**

We therefore can use the following regular expression.

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:(?:[,.]\d)? (?:[MmBb]illion|thousand)\b|[,.]\dMb|,\d{3}b)
```

Factoring out the end-of-string anchor we obtain

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:(?:[,.]\d)? (?:[MmBb]illion|thousand)|[,.]\dM|,\d{3})b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8oZuW/1)